# Gradle, Java 8 and 9+, variant aware example

Tags: gradle, java-8, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I read Gradle is *variant aware*

well, I'd like to have a library come in two variants, one for jdk8 and one for jdk9+

Although I am reading again and again the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_model.html#sec:abm_configuration_attributes) I just can’t grasp which structure the project should have

One repository, two branches? Or a single branch with different directories?

Is there a clear example somewhere? I tried to search but I couldn’t find anything

Edit: related, [Gradle Module Metadata](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_gradle_module_metadata.html) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-6-features)

Comment: [This blog post](https://blog.gradle.org/guava) may help. It is basically the same idea here: Java 8 variant and a Java 6/7 (Android) variant